# Python 3.0.1 collections.Counter

Tags: python, collections, python-3.x, counter

In Python 3.0.1, I am attempting to use the `Counter` part of the `collections` module
Everywhere I look in the documentation...there is nothing that says this part of the module is not available in Python 3.0.1. But...

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import counter
from Collections import Counter
from Collections import counter
```

All yield errors for me...Why is this???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collections.Counter` was added in version 3.1. Either upgrade to 3.2 or implement the class yourself. There's a recipe [here.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/)

Comment: It appears that recipe was written for Python 2.x, if you are using it with Python 3.0 you will need to replace all `iteritems` function references to `items`.

Answer (score 3):

Do **NOT** use 3.0 -- it was basically dead on arrival as it has serious problems.  Get 3.2, or at the very least 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

the `Counter` class did not exist in the 3.0.1 release of python. it appeared with 3.1 version.

Answer (score 2):

Counter does not appear in the manual for 3.0.1: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/collections.html

It seems to first show up in 3.1:
http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/library/collections.html